# urlのget parameterを上書きする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on railsで簡単なリストページを作成しています。
ページングのためにURLでoffsetとlimitというget parameterを渡しています。
そのパラメータをコントローラで空白、文字列等の場合はデフォルト値で「0」を入れていますが、
URLはそのままになっていて少し不自然な気がします。
例えば、0.0.0.0:3000/admin/historeis?offset='a'&limit=20のような場合、
コントローラーではoffsetに「０」を入れて、idが「0」のデータから取り出すようにする。
でも、URLは上記のママ。なのでURLを
0.0.0.0:3000/admin/historeis?offset=0&limit=20
上記のように上書きしたいです。

次は自分のコントローラーのコードです。

```
def index
  @offset = offset
  @limit = limit

  @histories = history.limit(@limit).offset(@offset))
end

def offset
  return 0 if params[:offset].nil?
  return 0 unless params[:offset] =~ /^[0-9]*$/
end

def limit
  return 10 if params[:limit].nil?
  return 10 unless params[:limit] =~ /^[0-9]*$/
end
```

Answer (score 1):

URLに含まれる（GET）パラメータは、パラメータという名前が付いている通り、ユーザーからの入力値であり、それそのものを一回のリクエストで変更するのは難しいかと思います。

一度、リダイレクトをはさみ、処理をするのはいかがでしょうか。

```
DEFAULT_OFFSET_PARAM = 0
DEFAULT_LIMIT_PARAM = 0

before_action :validate_offset, only: :index
before_action :validate_limit, only: :index

def index
  # ...
end

def valid_number?(num)
  return false if num.nil?
  return false unless num =~ /^[0-9]*$/
  true
end

def validate_offset
  unless valid_number?(params[:offset])
    redirect_to histories_path(offset: DEFAULT_OFFSET_PARAM, limit: params[:limit])
  end
end

def validate_limit
  unless valid_number?(params[:limit])
    redirect_to histories_path(offset: params[:offset], limit: DEFAULT_LIMIT_PARAM)
  end
end
```